# Javascript get index value using this variable

Tags: javascript

When I click li links, I would like to get index value using this variable. How I can achieve it?

```js
let liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
    liList[i].onclick = function () {
       alert(liList.indexOf.call(this));        //I want to use this to get i value
    };
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>33</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `liList.indexOf(this)` ?  Though the `i` is `let` scoped, so not sure why you couldn't just use it.  Or use a `forEach` with a closure to get the index and not need this logic.

Comment: what do you mean by index value?

Comment: liList.indexOf(this) , this is only example I actually cannot find any method to get it. I know alert(i) I can get index (e.g. I click 11, it return 0). Since I learn to simulate jquery index() method, I want to use this to get index

Comment: Did you try my answer below sir? Please let me know. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I try. But I want not to use i variable, is it possible use "this" to get i value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the index of the clicked value there is no need to do the indexOf, you have the index in your loops `i` var:

```js
let liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
    liList[i].onclick = function () {
       console.log(i);
    };
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>33</li>
</ul>
```

And if you really want to do `indexOf()` you should transform that [HTMLCollection](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_htmlcollection.asp) returned from getElementsByTagName() to an array first:

```js
let liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
    liList[i].onclick = function () {
        let arr = Array.prototype.slice.call( liList, 0 ); // transform in array
        console.log(arr.indexOf(this));
    };
 }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>11</li>
    <li>22</li>
    <li>33</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, this is really I want, but i also thank all quick reply and help

Comment: I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix your problem. Thanks

```js
    let liList = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (let i = 0; i < liList.length; i++) {
        liList[i].onclick = function () {
           console.log(liList[i].innerHTML);  /* li value that you want to get or */  
           console.log(i); /* Index value that you want to get */
        };
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>22</li>
  <li>33</li>
</ul>
```